# How to round with fractional digits in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I round up two digits after the comma?

```
Ex: I have a 3,7512 . I need 3,76 .
```

Comment: What must be the result if the value is: `3,7501` and `3,750` and `3,7459`?

Comment: According to the implied logic in the example (always round up after 2 digits), it would be `3,76`, `3,75`, and `3,75`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```
double value = 0.01 * Math.Ceiling(100.0 * originalValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It accepts a second argument that determines how many fractional digits you want to round.

```
Math.Round(3.7512, 2) // this rounds up to 3.75
Math.Round(3.7572, 2) // this rounds up to 3.76
```

Comment: It rounds to 3.75. While i need 3.76.
I have to round up all the time.

Comment: But then, what is the logic? 3,7512 is closer to 3,75 than to 3,76. I don't understand your logic.

Comment: Logic is simple. It's lab project I got in my university :)